# Is there a way to make a custom folding block in PhpStorm in SQL editing area?

Tags: phpstorm

I have a long SQL query and I want to fold parts of it in PhpStorm (I use 2018.1.2 x64), in SQL editing area. I can fold the whole query: there's a 'plus' sign next to the 'select' word. But I can't fold parts of the query. For example, inside of select.

In PHP or JS I would use curly-brackets-block for the purpose.

Comment: You can always fold custom selection.

Comment: Oh, great. The question is, how exactly do I do that

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-folding-commands.html -- "Fold Selection" ?..

Comment: It works in PHP or JS files. Not in SQL-editing area, unfortunately

Comment: "Ctrl +/-" ignores selection. It just folds and unfolds the whole fragment, mrked "+/-" by default (everything starting from "select" in my case)

Comment: Really? Works fine here (those 2 lines are custom folding region made by the aforementioned action): https://postimg.cc/image/692ewaa71/ Show yours (whole file) -- maybe you have some "nuances"...

Comment: *""Ctrl +/-" ignores selection."* Why do you use `Ctrl +/-`? You should be usin `Ctrl + .` .. as stated on that page. https://postimg.cc/image/e330hoaa5/

Comment: Ah, I'm being inattentive! Ctrl + . does the job. Thank you